# Magento remove + percentage from option dropdowns

Tags: magento-1, price, custom-options

My client is using the MageWorx plugin Advanced Product Options but wants to remove the (+ percentage) from the option drop downs. I've managed to remove the (+ price) no problem, but I cannot figure out where to remove the percentage.

Here's the page where the options are: http://magento-28691-62076-166572.cloudwaysapps.com/products/business-cards/business-cards.html

If you choose an option from the first dropdown, then you can choose from the second one (quantity) which will adjust the price, but the following drop downs still have the (+ 20%) etc. in them.

Does anyone know how these can be removed, as I'm not comfortable with the Magento code base and don't want to go playing around in Core plugin files which could break it.

Comment: If the extension does it, you wouldn't need to touch the Core files but the module files rather. Even better would be to extends the module files and do your changes there. Depends on what version of Magento you're using, could you update your question and add the appropriate tag pls?

Comment: This link might be helpful for you : https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-remove-price-in-product-option.html Though it is used to remove pricing, Make sure you check the extension file for select.php if exists then you should be editing that file and not core. And in case you need to edit core file for changes move it to app/code/local/ and then modify that file.

Comment: @Julien Lachal This is my first post and some of the tags I tried to use wouldn't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes in:

```
 app/code/community/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Catalog/Product/Option.php
```

in the *getFormattedOptionPrice* method:

```
public function getFormattedOptionPrice($_value)
{
    if ($_value->getPriceType() == self::PRICE_TYPE_OPTIONS_PERCENT) {
        $priceStr = '+'.(int)$_value->getPrice().'%';
    } else {
        $priceStr = Mage::helper('mageworx_customoptions')->getFormatedOptionPrice($this->getProduct(), $this, $_value);
    }
    return $priceStr;
}
```

just remove **`+`** . That's it.

The best way to do that is by copying the file into the local code pool.

Comment: Thanks for this, but what do you mean by copying the file into the local code pool? You'll have to excuse my ignorance, I am not a Magento developer and have not used it much.

Comment: Copy the file: 
app/code/community/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Catalog/Product/Option.php 
into
 app/code/local/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Catalog/Product/Option.php 
and implement all changes in the copy.